# Change end of line character for user input in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, system-calls

I am writing a calculator program in nasm and I would like to read user input until user enters =. In other words, I don't want the user to press enter for end of input line. Is there any special system call or something for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Linux or OS X system calls for reading input from a Unix TTY, the normal way is to put the TTY in raw mode with ioctl so you see every character as its typed, no line-editing.

But you can also set the TTY's `eol` (end of line) character.  e.g. from the command line,

```
stty eol =
```

You can test it with `cat` and see that `=` (as well as newline) submit your buffered text to the kernel so cat sees it and prints it.

Use `strace` to see what system calls `stty` uses to do that.  It's `ioctl(0, TCGETS, { stuf ...}) = 0`

(The `stty sane` and/or `reset` shell commands will reset your terminal settings back to normal after playing with stuff.)